# How to run a thread in the background?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a (Winform) program in .NET 3.5, which sends files to ftp servers. I use a thread in the background, because I want to send files to ftp and show a progress bar at the same time.

However, I have problem when the program execution is on `Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();` the program shows `MessageBox.Show("Výsledek odesílání naleznete v souboru vysledek.txt", "Výsledek")` and after that jumps back to `reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)`. I don't understand why.

This is my code:

```
private void Odeslat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button2.Enabled = false;

    Thread thread = new Thread(Process);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();  

    MessageBox.Show("Výsledek odesílání naleznete v souboru vysledek.txt", "Výsledek");
    button1.Enabled = true;
    button2.Enabled = true;
}

public void Process()
{
    foreach (string Prodejna in SeznamProdejen)
    {
        i = i + 1;
        Update1(i);

        //some long task
        ..............
        Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();   //PROBLEM
        reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        reqStream.Close();
        .................//some other code
    }
}

public void Update1(int i)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action<int>(Update1), new object[] { i });
        return;
    }

    progressBar1.Value = i;
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? You have started background thread at `thread.Start();`,  so from this moment your code in `Odeslat_Click` is executed in parallel to `Process()` - it is normal behaviour. Why do you think it is something wrong here?

Comment: What behavior do you expect?

Comment: @Sievajet I want to foreach (string Prodejna in SeznamProdejen) send file and update progressbar, but progressbar.value is null...i dont know why..

Answer (score 1):

It directly reaches the message box because the uploads happens in another thread and therefore asynchronously.

If you want to wait for the upload thread to finish you'll have to join it:

```
thread.Start();  
thread.Join();
MessageBox.Show("Výsledek ...");
```

Comment: :Thanks, but now my progressbar not update, value of progressbar is still 0